# ros::init() needed for ROS Gazebo plugin?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After reading [this thread on the Gazebo-list](http://kforge.ros.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2013-February/004404.html) about plugins residing inside the Gazebo ROS node, I found out that my plugin is running fine without the ros::init() call.

The tutorials (e.g. [here for 1.3](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/ros_enabled_model_plugin#Model_Plugin)) however make use of this initialisation. So now I wonder, if it is necessary or not?

Since, the plugin is loaded into the Gazebo node, it would make sense to me, that ros::init is not needed (similar to nodelets in ROS).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1493/ros::init()-needed-for-ros-gazebo-plugin?/) by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 129 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo does not call `ros:init`. It's up to one of your plugins (or a plugin that you load) to call `ros::init`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-08**:
Right, but the question is, if it is needed. My plugin for example has subs & pubs, but since it is loaded into gazebo, which is also acting as a ROS node, it works fine without calling ros::init(). So, I wonder in which case it is actually needed.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodríguez T](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26/adolfo-rodr%C3%ADguez-t/) on 2013-03-08**:
Gazebo is acting as a ROS node because someone inside the process called ros::init(). If it wasn't your plugin, some other plugin must have done it, as standalone Gazebo does not do it. So yes, it *is* needed to make your plugin robust to the case when it's the only ROS-enabled component inside the Gazebo process.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-08**:
You should have posted this as an answer. :-)  Anyway, if I remove all plugins I am using, Gazebo is still showing up as a ROS node and is publishing/subscribing to topics. AFAIK this requires a ros::init(). Am I missing something?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-15**:
ROS wraps gazebo. So when you say you run gazebo, you're probably running a special gazebo script that loads in a plugin that in turn calls ros::init. Take a look in the `simulator_gazebo` package.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think in some cases it may fail. Most of the `gazebo_ros_*` plugins in ROS have the following code:

```
if (!ros::isInitialized())
{
  int argc = 0;
  char** argv = NULL;
  ros::init(argc, argv, "gazebo", ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler |
                                  ros::init_options::AnonymousName);
}
```

So, probably in your case ROS is just initialized already. Though, I am not sure what "initialized" means in this case.

Boris

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-29**:
This is no longer true, we have removed the fallback init() function from all gazebo plugins.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The recommended way to check for ROS being initialized for all Gazebo plugins has been documented in this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins).

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/143/bit-pirate/) on 2013-07-28**:
This contains useful background information. Thanks!

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2016-09-11**:
link is dead. Replace with http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins probably

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2017-02-20**:
ive updated the link, thanks